# I a .NET 7 console app how can I make use of BindingSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

I'm writing a .NET 7 console application that will only run on Windows x64.

I need to use the `BindingSource` class that lives in *System.Windows.Forms.dll*, but this assembly isn't part of the *Microsoft.NETCore.App* Framework (which is what the new-project-wizard of VS suggests for my console app).

How can I add this dependency? What settings should I make in my .csproj file?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a BindingSource in a console application?  BindingSource is a WinForms class (as you point out).

Comment: What do you think that using a `BindingSource` will do for you? The whole point of the `BindingSource` class is to provide a single source of truth for bound data but, if there's no UI, what exactly do you want to bind your data to? Whatever it is that you're trying to do, the correct way does not involve a `BindingSource`. If you explain what actual problem you're trying to solve, rather than how you're trying to solve it, then we can explain the best way to do that.

Comment: I have good reasons for using the BindingSource in this case. I am aware that it is a piece of the WinForms world.

Answer (score 1):

To include System.Windows.Forms.dll in your project, you can modify your project file (.csproj). You'll need to specify the reference to the assembly explicitly.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work for me. However you helped me as I had the idea of trying to add 

<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>

to my .csproj file and that resolved the problem. Thanks